# Getting HTTP Error: 400 Bad Request on GIF or video upload on Twitter

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am using **Twitter** npm package to make a simple app that can upload gif or video to the platform. Getting *400 Bad Request* error on the *FINALIZE* step.
I can't understand why am I getting this error. I have structured my code as the example provided by the package and the Twitter docs. There is not much discussion about this error on stack overflow and in Twitter forums, they are saying that if a media file doesn't pass validation then this error is produced but they didn't specify the validations. If someone can explain why is it happening then that would be a great help.

```
let fs = require('fs')
let path = require('path')

const keys = require('./config')

const client = new Twitter(keys)

let mediaIdString = ''
let mediaId = 0

//  reading file (GIF)
const gifFile = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'memes', 'gif1.gif'))

//  getting file details
const gifFileStat = fs.statSync(path.join(__dirname, 'memes', 'gif1.gif'))
const gifSize = gifFileStat.size
const contentType = 'image/gif'

console.log(`gif size in bytes ==> ${gifSize}`)

//  calling uploadMedia
uploadMedia().then((result) => {
    console.log('UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL')
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})

function uploadMedia () {
    //    STEP 1 (INIT)
    return client.post('media/upload', {
        command: 'INIT',
        total_bytes: gifSize,
        media_type: contentType
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(`INIT \t response ==> ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)

        mediaIdString = response.media_id_string
        mediaId = response.media_id

        console.log(`mediaId ==> ${mediaId}`)

        console.log(`media id string ==> ${mediaIdString}`)

        //  step 2 (APPEND)
        return client.post('media/upload', {
            command: 'APPEND',
            media_id: mediaIdString,
            media_data: gifFile,
            segment_index: 0
        })
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(`APPEND \t response ==> ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)

        //  STEP 3 (STATUS)
        return client.get('media/upload', {
            command: 'STATUS',
            media_id: mediaIdString
        })
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(`STATUS \t response ==> ${response}`)

        //  STEP 4 (FINALIZE)
        return client.post('media/upload', {
            command: 'FINALIZE',
            media_id: mediaIdString
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that causing you to get `Error: HTTP Error: 400 Bad Request` is the data you get by `fs.readFileSync` is a **raw binary file** rather than **base64-encoded file**. API reference of Twitter states that:

> **media** : The raw binary file content being uploaded. Cannot be used with `media_data`
>
> **media_data** : The base64-encoded file content being uploaded. Cannot be used with `media`
>
> [POST media/upload > Parameters](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload.html)

So you should use `media` parameter to pass the file instead of `media_data`.

The second issue that your **promise chain** while trying to use **chunked-upload approach** is a little bit problematic and it should actually look like this:

```
client.post('media/upload', {
  command: 'INIT',
  total_bytes: gifSize,
  media_type: contentType
}).then((response) => {
  mediaIdString = response.media_id_string;
  client.post('media/upload', {
    command: 'APPEND',
    media_id: mediaIdString,
    media: gifFile,
    segment_index: 0
  }).then((response) => {
    client.post('media/upload', {
      command: 'FINALIZE',
      media_id: mediaIdString,
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log('UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL');
    });
  });
});
```

I think you tried to write a **promise waterfall** but I believe it does not work quite well in this case or if it works then it requires even more code to write and there is no performance difference at all.

Additionally, there is no mention of `STATUS` command in [twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) package's [README.md](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/blob/296e82ede50ddace34ad64952fdfacfe8b1c65fc/examples/README.md#chunked-media) so it seems like `STATUS` is not supported by this library.

Comment: You are right about that I should use `media_data` with **base64** encoded file and `media` with **raw file** and I am aware of it, I was messing with the code out of frustration and posted the question without prior running it. And the approach of writing code won't produce any error, I was just avoiding nesting of promises. I think the problem lies with the **STATUS** step. After changing _media_data_ to `media` and removing the `STATUS` step, the code is working just fine. Thanks, for the response.

Comment: @neer17 I'm glad that I could help.

Comment: I think this `Twitter` package doesn't support _STATUS_ step, if you can include this in your answer then I would be pleased to accept that.

Comment: @neer17 sure, I've added.